# input month and year and get output that whole month date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried this code but I want to pass month and year parameter by using where condition.

```
WITH d AS
  (SELECT TRUNC ( to_date('01.2012','mm.yyyy'), 'MM' ) - 1 AS dt
  FROM dual
  )
SELECT dt + LEVEL  AS date_month

   FROM d 
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ADD_MONTHS (dt, 1) - dt
```

Comment: Can you write some example output you want to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by "pass month and year parameter by using where clause"? Why does it have to be a `WHERE` clause rather than some other mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `WHERE` clause and you can pass the year and month in as bind variables:

```sql
SELECT month_start + LEVEL - 1 AS date_month
FROM   (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( TO_DATE( :year, 'YYYY' ), 'YYYY' ), :month - 1 )
           AS month_start
  FROM   DUAL
)
CONNECT BY month_start + LEVEL - 1 < ADD_MONTHS( month_start, 1 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You're very close to the solution, can do such as

```
SQL> var mon number;
SQL> var year number;
SQL> begin :mon :=&mon; :year := &year; end; -- mon --> 4 and year --> 2020
  2  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
mon
---------
4
year
---------
2020

SQL> 
SQL> WITH d AS
  2  (
  3   SELECT TRUNC( to_date(lpad(:mon,2,'0')||'.'||:year,'mm.yyyy'), 'MM' ) - 1 AS dt
  4     FROM dual
  5  )
  6  SELECT dt + LEVEL AS date_month
  7    FROM d
  8  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ADD_MONTHS (dt, 1) - dt
  9  /
```

to list all the dates of *April 2020*. And replace those parameter values to the desired month and year combinations.

Comment: This will fail if you want February instead of April as you have hardcoded `4` into the query to meet the OP's arbitrary requirement of using the `WHERE` clause. You would be better to remove the `WHERE` clause entirely.

Comment: the problem is not related to february, but `where` clause you're right that no need to substitute variables in the where clause repeatedly @MT0 , thanks.